# How to unwrap a typescript generic internal type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a graph of generic classes, where the wrapped type is needed to specify other classes.

```
interface Data {
    id: number,
}

class EntityClass<T extends Data> {
    public data;

    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Result<T extends Data> {
    public data

    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Right now I'm passing both the type (`EntityClass<any>` and the internal type (`DataClass`), even though it always matches what would be `any` here.

```
function extract<Class extends EntityClass<any>, DataClass extends Data>(
    entity: Class
) : Result<DataClass> {}
```

Is there a way to "unwrap" the internal type of EntityClass, to avoid passing both? Here's what I'd like to do:

```
function extract<Class extends EntityClass<InternalClass>>(
    entity: Class
) : Result<InternalClass> {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This  a basic application of conditional types and their inference behavior

```
class EntityClass<T extends Data> {
    public data: T; // T assuming this should be T

    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

type GetDataClass<T  extends EntityClass<any>> = T  extends EntityClass<infer U > ? U: never;
function extract<Class extends EntityClass<any>>(
    entity: Class
) : Result<GetDataClass<Class>> { return null as any}
```

Or you can also do it with a type query as well, but that means you will be tied to the `data` field, the conditional type will extract the generic type based on structure without you having to specify a particular field.

```
function extract<Class extends EntityClass<any>>(
    entity: Class
) : Result<Class['data']> { return null as any}
```

You can read more about type queries and conditional types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)